# confusion about file I/O

Tags: file, io

I was asked by an interviewer, the question is simple, `find the top 100 from 1 million integers (32-bits)`.

When I was solving the question, I thought if I `put all the 1 million integers into the memory`, that would take up `4 MB space`.

My question probably has nothing to do with the interview question, but here it is:

if the 1 million integers are store in a file `num.txt`, and further more, I want to `read the all out` of file and `put them in memory` (store them in an array probably), then `how many IO will it take`?

Comment: Actually sir, there is a max of 3.8 megabytes at a max.  Unless every integer uses all 32 decimal places, your probably going to get something much smaller.  Right?  Assuming half of the million digits are only 16 long gets just 2.86102295 megabytes.

Comment: @DadeLamkins, yeah, you're right, but what I want to know is how many IO should it take if I want to read all the 32-bits integers out of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna do in this question if a scan. 
You wanna have an array, or perhaps a priority-queue, that holds 100 integers and just store the largest 100 you see.

You don't wanna take the take in the file one page at the time, perhaps using something like `mmap`.

the number of IO's will be the size of 1mio. integers divided by the pagesize.

Comment: do you mean that, if my pagesize is `4k`, then the IO will be `10^6*4 / 4k`, right?